# Configuring multiple relationships between entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have `Person` and `Course` Entities With multiple relationships:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Leader { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Teachers { get; set; }
    public virtual Person CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Person UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesUpdated { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesLead { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesTutored { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have the following mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasMany(x => x.Tutors)
                           .WithMany(p => p.CoursesTutored)
                           .Map(x =>
                               {
                                   x.MapLeftKey("PersonID");
                                   x.MapRightKey("CourseID");
                                   x.ToTable("Course_Tutors");
                               });
```

This works in that it sets up the `Course_Tutors` table as well as providing the course table with `Leader_PersonID`, `CreatedBy_PersonID` and `UpdatedBy_PersonID`.

However it also creates three extra `Person` columns in the course table: `Person_PersonID1`, `Person_PersonID2`, `Person_PersonID3`.

Can someone tell me how to get rid of these? I am assuming my mapping needs some more work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code First has problems identifying relationships by conversions when you have more than one relationship between two entities. You need to explicitly configure them.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
     .HasRequired(c => c.Leader)
     .WithMany(p => p.CoursesLead)
     .Map(m => m.MapKey("Leader_PersonID"));

modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
     .HasRequired(c => c.CreatedBy)
     .WithMany(p => p.CoursesCreated)
     .Map(m => m.MapKey("CreatedBy_PersonID"));

modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
     .HasRequired(c => c.UpdatedBy)
     .WithMany(p => p.CoursesUpdated)
     .Map(m => m.MapKey("UpdatedBy_PersonID"));
```

Comment: I thought that would do the job but its giving me the following error: Type Course_UpdatedBy is not defined in namespace StudentProject.EFRepository (Alias=Self)

Comment: @james Did you include all these mappings correctly? Are you using the previously created database structure with the new mappings? are there any others properties that you haven't mapped?

Comment: I Now get a "cyclical reference that is not allowed. [ Constraint name = Course_Tutors_Target ]". So close to fixing this!

Comment: @james Can not suggest any thing without seeing the `Tutor` class and the mapping between `Tutor` and `Course`.

Comment: Fixed! I added .WillCascadeOnDelete(false) to .HasRequired(c => c.CreatedBy) and removed x.MapLeftKey("PersonID") & x.MapRightKey("CourseID") from my original mapping. Got there in the end, thanks for the help.

Comment: @james Pleasure helping someone who's willing to experiment and learn.